# Unserialize offset error, string length seems too long

Tags: php, serialization

I am trying to unserialize a longtext (utf8_unicode_ci) from a database query, but when I do I get the following error.

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 6 of 737 bytes
```

I guessed that my string was invalid so I outputted it to the browser. I noticed the string length was a little longer then what it was actually supposed to be. When I copy and paste the output in the browser and hard code it into the php the sting length changes to a smaller one and the unserialize works.

Database string...

```
ASCII - string(737) "a:10:{s:2:"id";i:2234950;s:13:"full_describe";s:11:"Brace start";s:6:"person";s:17:"Dr Aalok Y Shukla";s:8:"datetime";s:25:"2014-01-06T09:00:00+00:00";s:8:"duration";i:30;s:11:"on_waitlist";b:0;s:10:"company_id";s:5:"35927";s:8:"attended";b:1;s:6:"_links";a:2:{s:4:"self";a:1:{s:4:"href";s:60:"http://uk.bookingbug.com/api/v1/admin/35927/bookings/2234950";}s:6:"client";a:1:{s:4:"href";s:57:"http://uk.bookingbug.com/api/v1/admin/35927/client/809828";}}s:11:"appointment";a:1:{s:11:"description";s:11:"Brace start";}}"
```

Copied and pasted string into php...

```
ASCII - string(517) "a:10:{s:2:"id";i:2234950;s:13:"full_describe";s:11:"Brace start";s:6:"person";s:17:"Dr Aalok Y Shukla";s:8:"datetime";s:25:"2014-01-06T09:00:00+00:00";s:8:"duration";i:30;s:11:"on_waitlist";b:0;s:10:"company_id";s:5:"35927";s:8:"attended";b:1;s:6:"_links";a:2:{s:4:"self";a:1:{s:4:"href";s:60:"http://uk.bookingbug.com/api/v1/admin/35927/bookings/2234950";}s:6:"client";a:1:{s:4:"href";s:57:"http://uk.bookingbug.com/api/v1/admin/35927/client/809828";}}s:11:"appointment";a:1:{s:11:"description";s:11:"Brace start";}}"
```

As you can see the strings are the same but the string from the database call shows the offset error.

Do I need to do some sort of decoding or formatting on the string returned from the database?

Thanks

Comment: They are the same but has different length. Did you check encodings of this strings (something like mb_detect_encoding)? I think you should convert 1st string into same encodings as the 2nd one.

Comment: also have you checked if there is any trailing spaces? `trim()`

Comment: @klipach I have checked the encoding using mb_detect_encoding() and they are both ASCII. Any ideas why its doing this?

Comment: @bansi There are no trailing spaces are they would have shown in length using var_dump().

Comment: can you try $string = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $string) or $string = mb_convert_encoding ($string, 'US-ASCII', 'UTF-8') for the first string. According to length the second string is ASCII but the first one is not ASCII

Comment: @klipach I have tried both of them but still the same. http://pastebin.com/QJpMBJCT is an example of what I am doing and the output.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was serializing multidimensional arrays which causes problems.

To fix just base64_encode() the string before you use serialize and vise versa when you use unserialize.

```
//to safely serialize
$safe_string_to_store = base64_encode(serialize($multidimensional_array));

//to unserialize...
$array_restored_from_db = unserialize(base64_decode($encoded_serialized_string));
```

Article found at http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues

Hope this helps others